# For loop in Python and data types

Tags: python, for-loop, int

I am trying to figure out what happens with the variable in a for loop.

```
i=2
for i in "1234":
    print i*2
    break
```

I can understand how is this loop executed because i is an integer and it is searched in a string. How does this work?

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: How does **what** work? You need to be clearer in your question here.

Comment: I know how do to what I want, I can't figure out why this is executed.

Comment: Here's a technical description of for loops, if that's what you're after (which it probably isn't): https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement

Comment: It is executed because you asked Python to execute it. That's still not a clear problem description. What parts don't you understand? Have you tried experimenting with the code to help your understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> i=2
>>> print(type(i))
<class 'int'>
>>> for i in '1234':  # i is reassigned
...   print(type(i))
...   print(i*2)
... 
<class 'str'>
11
<class 'str'>
22
<class 'str'>
33
<class 'str'>
44
```

`i` is reassigned at the beginning of your for loop and is no longer an int.

In particular, Python is not "searching the string" for your int. It is *iterating over* the string because of your for loop. `i` is then the iteration variable, and when you loop over a string it goes character by character. Similarly, Python overloads multiplication for strings, so some string s times some int n comes out to s repeated n times.

Answer (score 0):

Never initialize a loop variable to an existing variable, and the `break` will cause only the first iteration to occur so you should probably get rid of it. Otherwise, the loop would be pointless.

```
i = 2

for j in "1234":
    print j * 2
```

The output is:

```
11
22
33
44
```

Comment: Yeah, I absent mindedly wrote that, but I fixed it.